# Change Model value based on other values?

Tags: angularjs

I have a model with several values that are tied to input fields. I would like to update other attributes of that model whenever some of these attributes change. here is an example:

```
<input type='number' name='hours' ng-model='project.hours' />
<input type='number' name='rate' ng-model='project.rate' />
<span>{{ project.price }}
```

I would like to update the price attribute whenever there is a change in either the hours or rates field. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create watch expressions on the variables. A natural place to do this is in the controller - something like:

```js
var updatePrice = function(){ 
  //you might have to do null checks on the scope variables
  $scope.project.price = $scope.project.hours * $scope.project.rate; 
}
$scope.$watch('project.hours',updatePrice);
$scope.$watch('project.rate',updatePrice);
```

Another possibility is to use the ngChange directive on the input fields:

```
$scope.updatePrice = updatePrice;

<input type='number' name='hours' ng-model='project.hours' ng-change="updatePrice()" />
<input type='number' name='rate' ng-model='project.rate' ng-change="updatePrice()" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could define `price` as a calculation either in the markup or on your object.  The benefit to this is it doesn't require any watches and presumably if you do submit these to a backend server you probably should be recalculating it considering the user could manipulate that prior to submit.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wyiKlybVh94Fr3BDiYiZ?p=preview

Controller:

```
 $scope.project = {
  hours: 100,
  rate: 25,
  price: function() {
    return this.hours * this.rate;
  }
};
```

Then:

```
<input type='number' name='hours' ng-model='project.hours' />
<input type='number' name='rate' ng-model='project.rate' />
<span>{{ project.price() }}  OR {{project.hours * project.rate}} </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

And alternatively you can use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) (example in an angular 1.5 component):

Controller:

```
self.setPrice = function() {
  self.project.price = self.project.hours * self.project.rate;
};
```

Markup:

```
<input type="number" name="hours" ng-model="$ctrl.project.hours" ng-change="$ctrl.setPrice()">
<input type="number" name="rate" ng-model="$ctrl.project.rate" ng-change="$ctrl.setPrice()">
<span>{{ $ctrl.project.price }}</span>
```

This is useful when the calculated value is part of an entity that needs to be passed wholely through a REST call.